# Remote Debugging Node.js in Docker with VS Code

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, pm2

I'm having trouble connecting to a remote container's Node.js app in VS Code for debugging.

Here's my setup:

1. Docker

   I have port `9331` exposed in my Docker setup as shown here:

   ```bash
   > docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" -a

   CONTAINER ID   NAMES               PORTS
   6ae87a55054b   container_name      0.0.0.0:9331->9331/tcp
   ```
2. "Attach To Running Container" in VS Code
3. `launch.json`

   ```json
   {
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Attach",
               "port": 9331,
               "request": "attach",
               "skipFiles": [
                   "<node_internals>/**"
               ],
               "type": "node",
               "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
               "restart": true,
               "timeout": 120e3
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. PM2 shows `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9331`

   I've tried `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9331`, and `--inspect-brk`, and also tried leaving out the port number.

   ```
   │ interpreter args  │ --inspect=0.0.0.0:9331                              │
   │ script id         │ 0                                                   │
   │ exec cwd          │ /api                                                │
   │ exec mode         │ cluster_mode                                        |
   | script path       │/api/src/server.js
   ```

   But when I click the play button to launch, and/or add a debugger, it won't break.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change PM2 from Cluster Mode:

```
mode: "cluster"
```

to Fork Mode:

```
mode: "fork"
```

It seems cluster mode doesn't pass on that `inspect` port, which is why it wouldn't connect.